# Aspectj: weaving for a 3rd party jar

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have some common questions regarding aspectj weaving against 3rd party jars.

I know there're 3 ways to weaving: compile-time, post-compile-time (binary), load-time.

If I go with post compile time weaving, I have to maintain a SomeThingWoven.jar which derived from SomethingOrigin.jar, And in runtime, I should use the SomeThingWoven.jar, right?

If I go with load-time weaving, all I need to provide is an aop.xml and a -javaagent setting, right?

Which way is better?

Any performance (runtime cpu/memory) differences? (By "performance", I mean after warm-up, i.e. sever has been running for a while and all classes have been loaded)

Thanks

Leon

Comment: Leon, I think I have answered your question on the AspectJ mailing list. Does it make sense to ask everywhere?

Comment: @kriegaex It makes sense for googlers arriving here like me. Would you (or @anuni) mind posting the answer here (after 7 years...) so it can help more people.

Comment: @lidlesseye: https://www.mail-archive.com/aspectj-users@eclipse.org/msg08082.html